# Rider on Mac gives me cannot resolve symbol on linq methods like Any and Skip, whyP

Tags: c#, rider

Rider on Mac. Old asp.net project.

I am in the process of building the solution for the first time, but getting different errors.

I am getting this cannot resolve symbol on Any() and Skip() and different linq methods.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have a `using` directive for `System.Linq`?

Comment: I thought I did. Whenever I used visual studio, the using in the code behind would suffice.
Not it seems I need to add <%@ Import namespace="System.Linq" %> whenever I want to use linq methods.

Comment: Some of the old Web Forms projects give me all sorts of problems with intelisense.  So it sounds like you got it working?